# I need help with solving this differential equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Solve diffential equation: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-3\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\:=\:0$

where $u = ax + y$ and $v = x$ (hint: pick a reasonable $a$)

I just started studying calculus 3, I don't know how to solve this problem. I'm looking for help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f_x - 3 f_y =0$$

$$f_x =f_u u_x + f_v v_x = af_u + f_v$$

$$f_y = f_u u_y + f_v v_y = f_u$$

$$af_u + f_v - 3 f_u = 0.$$

Now, let $a=3$.

$$f_v = 0.$$

Integrate with respect to $v$ so $$f=g(u), \quad \text{a function of } u \text{ only}.$$

$$f=g(3x+y).$$

Comment: thanks buddy, this looks much clearer to understand than the solution I have in my textbook.

Comment: You are welcome!